# Using Rack gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rack

I'm trying to use a stupid little Rack gem I just wrote in my Rails project, but I keep on getting an `uninitialized constant` error whenever I call it. This is driving me insane because I've [already written Rack gems](https://github.com/appgrinders/rack-conditional-response-headers) before, and *those* work in my Rails projects just fine.

**In my Gemfile:**

```
gem 'hide_heroku', :git => 'https://github.com/ykessler/hide-heroku'
```

**In my application.rb:**

```
module Tester
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.middleware.use Rack::HideHeroku
```

But starting my local server, I get:

> uninitialized constant Rack::HideHeroku (NameError)

**The gem:**

```
module Rack

  class HideHeroku

    def initialize(app)
      @app=app
    end

    def call(env)
      @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
      @request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      [@status, _apply_headers, @response]
    end

    private

      def _apply_headers
        if /\.herokuapp\.com\/?.*/ =~ @request.url
          @headers['X-Robots-Tag'] = 'noindex, nofollow'
        end
        @headers
      end

  end

end
```

See it here: https://github.com/ykessler/hide-heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is probably the project's structure. You need to have a `lib/hide_heroku.rb` file in your gem, which bootstraps the gem, or you need to specify the require path on your gem line, like so:

```
gem 'hide_heroku', :git => 'https://github.com/ykessler/hide-heroku', :require => "rack/hide_heroku"
```

(Or you can just `require 'rack/hide_heroku'` in your app).

Bundler will try to require the gem's name when you call `Bundler.setup`, but if you aren't using that file structure, it can't find your files to include.

Comment: Chris- Thanks so much- that was exactly it